# Problems with my random number generator

Tags: c, random

Im learning basic C on my own and trying to create a poker client. I have an array with cards (called `kortArray`) and a players hand (called `kortHand`). My implementation does not shuffle the deck, but add all 52 cards in sequence and then randomly selecting 5 cards from the deck. I've added a flag (called `draget`) which tells if a card has been picked up befor or not.

Now, when I run the algorithm below, it usually generates five random numbers which makes the player's or computer's hand. But sometimes it generates less then five numbers, even though I've specifically stated to generate five accepted values.

I have two loops, one that runs five times, and the other is nested and runs until it finds a card which hasn't yet been picked. The `printf` in the middle tells me that this algorithm doesn't always generate five accepted numbers, and when that happens the player's hand contains cards with nonsense-values.

```
srand((unsigned)(time(0)));
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {                        
    int x = rand()%52 + 1;
    while (kortArray[x].draget!=1) {                
        x = rand()%52 + 1;
        if (kortArray[x].draget != 1) {
            printf("%i\n", x);
            kortArray[x].draget = 1;
            kortHand[i] = kortArray[x];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't indent properly.

Comment: @ManojR: Codereview is not for debugging any more than SO is

Comment: Could you please let us know when the code in the question is the real code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem still lies in the +1 for the random numbers.

Also, you are first checking in the the first assignment to x if the card is already picked, and than you assign it to an other card.

Why not use something like:

```
int nr_cards_picked = 0             /* Number of uniquely picked cards in hand */
/* Continue picking cards until 5 unique cards are picked. */
while (nr_cards_picked < 5) {
    x = rand() % 52;                         /* Take a random card */
    if (kortArray[x].draget == 0) {
        /* Pick this card. */
        kortArray[x].draget = 1;             /* Card is picked */
        kortHand[i]         = kortArray[x];  /* Add picked card to hand */
        nr_cards_picked++;
    }
}
```

Forgive compiler errors; I don't have a compiler near here.

This case you only have one time a random number call.

Theoretically it might never end but this is not likely.

Comment: oh, that's just a typo. I've been trying different approaches so it's supposed to be 52+1. Still gives me the some problem :)

Comment: @JimmyGustafsson: "that's just a typo" How can we know what else is "just a typo"? Make a _testcase_ so that we're not all wasting our time.

Comment: @JimmyGustafsson: Also, that "fix" doesn't change what Michel said. I suggest reading his answer again

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```
   int x = rand()%52+1; 
      while (kortArray[x].draget!=1){                 
        x = rand()%52;
```

Arrays in C are indexed starting at 0.  Your first call to rand() will generate a value starting at 1.  Assuming that you declared kortArray[] to hold 52 values, there is about a 2% chance that you will overrun the array.

Your first call to rand() generates values in the range 1..52.  Your second call generates 0..51.  ONE OF THEM IS WRONG.

Comment: oh, that's just a typo. I've been trying different approaches so it's supposed to be 52+1. Still gives me the some problem :)

Answer (score 2):

A few things of note.

First of all, random number generators are not guaranteed to be random if you do a mod operation on them. Far better is to divide it out into the 52 segments, and choose like that.

Secondly, you would be far better off moving your call to generate a random number inside the while loop to the end, or just not generate one at the beginning of the for loop.

Where your problem is coming into play is that you are sometimes leaving the while loop without actually entering it, because you are randomly generating a number before you enter the loop.

Given all of this, I would do code somewhat as follows:

```
srand((unsigned)(time(0)));
for(i=0;i<5;i++){         
     x=-1;               
     while (kortArray[x].draget!=1){                
          x = floor(rand()*52);
      }
      printf("%i\n", x);
      kortArray[x].draget=1;
      kortHand[i]=kortArray[x];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the faults. I had a working solution provied before you posted but giving you +1 for giving me a working solution aswell. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The nested loop is only entered when kortArray[x].draget is not 1.  So everytime it is 1, nothing is done and no card is assigned.  First make sure you have a unique x and then in all cases update kortHand[i]

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest a different algorithm:

1. create a random number between 0 and number of cards in deck
2. assign the card from that position to the appropriate hand
3. swap the last card to that postion
4. decrease the number of cards in the deck by 1.
5. continue with 1 until the necessary number of cards are dealt.

This way, you get rid of the flag and you can guarantee linear performance. No need to check whether a card has already been dealt or not.